# How to merge in P4 after a merge is messed up

Tags: perforce, p4v

So I did a merge through cmd which did not end up well, so I undid that CL (through visual client), now if I try to merge the 2 streams again I get a window saying `Integration errors: //project_stream/main/... - all revision(s) already integrated.` Does it mean there is no way to do the merge again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you undo an integration via `p4 undo` and the `dm.integ.undo` configurable is set you can just re-do an integration exactly as you tried to do.

```
(p4 help undoc)
        dm.integ.undo            0 Enable re-integration of undone changes
```

If those two conditions can't be met (i.e. you did the undo with a version of P4V that doesn't use the native `undo` command and/or you can't get your admin to flip that configurable setting), you have to re-integrate with the `-f` flag.

The `-f` flag forces integration without regard to previous history, which allows you to redo an integration -- however, you need to explicitly tell it which revisions/changelists to integrate, and/or take extra care during the resolve process.  Look carefully at the integration records from your original changelist to figure out what the earliest source changelist would have been, and do:

```
p4 integ -f source/...@SOURCE_START,@now target/...
```

The revision *before* `SOURCE_START` will be used as the base during the resolve process.